# The difference between characteristic, feature, aspect, attribute and quality, their definitions are defined using each other

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-in-context, definition, idioms-in-context

It's annoying the Dictionary always happens to me this absurdity:

Characteristic - distinguishing **feature** or **quality**

Feature - a distinctive **attribute** or **aspect** of something

Attribute - regard a **quality** or **feature** as a **characteristic** of or possessed by, **quality** or **feature** regarded as a **characteristic** or inherent part of someone or something

Quality - distinctive **attribute** or **characteristic** possessed by

For a partly ignorant on the English Lexicon person if you do not know these words it's going to be challenging to know their meaning and more their differences because they are defined using each other, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are all very similar, and to master the differences takes time and experience.  Just in case it helps, here are some words that share their roots:

characterize, character, inspect, spectacles, spectator, speculate, contribute, distribute, tributary, tribute, qualia, qualify, equal

Importantly, though, be aware that "feature" and "attribute" have other meanings when used as verbs.  The verb meanings are closely related to their noun forms.  "Attribute" is pronounced differently when used as a verb - as a noun, the first syllable is emphasized.  As a verb, the second syllable is emphasized.

Comment: So to understand it's nuances I need to apply etymology e.g. knowing it's root? If yes.. what exactly I need to learn to apply what you are advising to do?

Comment: How does using this: characterize, character, inspect, spectacles, spectator, speculate, contribute, distribute, tributary, tribute, qualia, qualify, equal will help me knowing their thorough definitions?

Comment: It may or may not help you memorize everything. But for example, all of the ones with *spec-* have something to do with vision/seeing. The last, *speculate* doesn't literally mean to look at something with your eyes, but rather to see something in your mind.  And *trib-* is also easy - those words all have something to do with giving. For the most part, the noun forms of your words mean the same thing, and are interchangeable. Mostly, though, you should just look at (and listen to) a lot of examples to see which ones we favor in a given situation.

Answer (score 1):

Pablo, aren't these almost identical in Spanish?

Quality - cualidad
Attribute - atributo
Characteristic - característica
Feature - facción (característica)